# Put random value from array in other array letter by letter

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void initRandom() {
    srand(time(NULL));
}

int intUniformRnd(int a, int b){
    return a + rand() % (b-a+1);
}

const char* animaisQuatro[] = {"gato", "urso","vaca"};

int main() {
    char quatro[4] = {'*' , '*' , '*', '*'};

    initRandom();
    printf("%s\n", animaisQuatro[intUniformRnd(0,2)]);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%c", quatro[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have this code that give me a random animal from the array `const char* animaisQuatro[] = {"gato", "urso","vaca","lapa"};` from here

```
                initRandom();
                printf("%s\n", animaisQuatro[intUniformRnd(0,2)]);
```

and then I want to put that random animal in another array letter by letter but I don't know how

Comment: Posted code does not compile.  Better to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

First I reduced your code to a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (something you should do whenever you ask a question):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void initRandom() {
    srand(time(NULL));
}

int intUniformRnd(int a, int b){
    return a + rand() % (b-a+1);
}

const char* animaisQuatro[] = {"gato", "urso","vaca"};

int main() {
    char quatro[4] = {'*' , '*' , '*', '*'};

    initRandom();
    printf("%s\n", animaisQuatro[intUniformRnd(0,2)]);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%c", quatro[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can proceed like this:

```
int main() {
    char quatro[4] = {'*' , '*' , '*', '*'};

    initRandom();
    
    // Get the animal name from a random position
    char* name = animaisQuatro[intUniformRnd(0, 2)];
    
    // Iterate four times
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        // Assign each `name` index to its respective `quatro` position
        quatro[i] = name[i];
    }
    
    printf("%s", quatro);
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

Tip: you can avoiding hardcoding the 2 when calling `intUniformRnd`. Note that

```
printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof(animaisQuatro));
printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof(char*));
printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof(animaisQuatro) / sizeof(char*));
```

outputs

```
24
8
3
```

Therefore, you can do

```
int length = (int) sizeof(animaisQuatro) / sizeof(char*);
int pos = intUniformRnd(0, length - 1);
```

This way, if you want to add more elements to `animaisQuatro`, you don't need to change the value inside `intUniformRnd`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to put that random animal in other array letter by letter

To copy a string to another character array, code could use

```
// Risky
strcpy(quatro, animaisQuatro[intUniformRnd(0,2)]);
```

That would overflow `quatro[]` if it is too small and leads to *undefined behavior*. (Bad)

---

A better way to copy and prevent buffer overflow and alert of a failure:

```
int len = snprintf(quatro, sizeof quatro, "%s", animaisQuatro[intUniformRnd(0,2)]);
if (len >= sizeof quatro) {
  fprintf(stderr, "quatro too small.\n");
}
```

---

Since C99 and selectively afterword, code could use a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99) to form a right-size `quatro` array.

```
const char *animal = animaisQuatro[intUniformRnd(0,2)];
size_t sz = strlen(animal) + 1;
char quatro[sz];
strcpy(quatro, animal);
```

---

Yet since `intUniformRnd[]` is constant, no need to copy the text, just copy the address to a pointer:

```
const char *quatro = animaisQuatro[intUniformRnd(0,2)];
```